# Python Array Diff

Tags: python, arrays

Write a function or program that will take 2 arrays of integers, "current" and "target", and produce 2 arrays representing an additions list and a deletions list such that applying the additions and deletions to the "current" array will yield the "target" array.

For example, given the following
inputs:

```
current =  [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9]

target = [1, 2, 5, 7, 9]
```

The outputs would be:

```
additions: [2, 7]

deletions: [3, 6, 8]
```

So that the following is true:

> current([1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9]) + additions([2, 7]) - deletions([3, 6, 8]) = target([1, 2, 5, 7, 9])

Solution:

So far I have this:

```
---------------------------

# import array function
from array import array

# create an integer array named current
current = array('i', [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9]) 

# add items from additions list into current array using the fromlist() method
additions = [2, 7]
current.fromlist(additions)

# remove items on deletions list from current array using the.     remove() method
current.remove(3)
current.remove(6)
current.remove(8)
```

---

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Can you clarify "doesn't work"? Do you get some error?

Comment: Apologies- it more or less works but thry are out of order on the final list once i step through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work for you...

```
def addlist(current,target):
        add = []
        intersection  = set(current) & set(target)
        for i in target:
                if i not in intersection:
                        add.append(i)
        return add

def removeList(current,target):
        remove = []
        intersection = set(current) & set(target)
        for i in current:
                if i not in intersection:
                        remove.append(i)
        return remove

def main():
        current = [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9]
        target = [1, 2, 5, 7, 9]
        print(addlist(current,target))
        print(removeList(current,target))

if __name__=="__main__":
        main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Below one should be easy to understand.

```
>>> current = [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9]
>>> target = [1, 2, 5, 7, 9]
>>> set(current) & set(target)
set([1, 5, 9])
>>> unique = list(set(current) & set(target))
>>> additions = [i for i in target if i not in unique]
>>> additions
[2, 7]
>>> deletions = [i for i in current if i not in unique]
>>> deletions
[3, 6, 8]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work as well.

```
current =  [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9]
target = [1, 2, 5, 7, 9]
additions=[x for x in target if x not in current]
deletions=[x for x in current if x not in target]
```